# Select segmentation by mouse and change the color in Cornerstone.js

Tags: javascript, image-processing, medical, medical-imaging, cornerstonejs

I’m using cornerstoneTools with the Cornerstone.js [DICOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM) view. I draw multiple segments by the Cornerstone.js segment tool and load the segments from RLE.

How can I select an existing segment by clicking it by mouse on the DICOM viewer?

Comment: What is "[RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLE)"? Right-to-left embedding? [RTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_script). [Run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)? Or something else?

Comment: "RLE" [is probably *"run-length encoding"*](https://dicom.nema.org/medical/Dicom/2017c/output/chtml/part05/sect_8.2.2.html) (for image compression). Or rather it should be *"from an RLE file"* or *"from a run-length encoded file"* (or the equivalent of a file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not possible to set the segmentation colour directly in Cornerstone.js. However, you can set the color in Cornerstone.js by switching your desired color from `colorLutTables`.

To do this, you have to do three steps:

1. Set `colorLutTables` with your list of colors, for example.

   ```
   const COLORLIST = [[255,0,0,255], [255,255,0,255],[0,0,255,255],[255,255,255,255]] // four colors red, yellow, blue and white

   // Set colorLut list when you initialise cornerstone tools

   const { configuration, state } = cornerstoneTools.getModule('segmentation');
   state.colorLutTables[0] = COLORLIST
   ```
2. Selecting the segment. This one. Also, there isn't any straight way to select a segment in Cornerstone.js. To do this, you have to use the Cornerstone.js tools event listener. You can use the `cornerstonetoolsmouseclick` event by attach this event to your Cornerstone.js-enabled element.

   ```
   element.addEventListener("cornerstonetoolsmouseclick", (e) => {
     const {getters: {segmentOfActiveLabelmapAtEvent}, setters: {deleteSegment}} = cornerstoneTools.getModule('segmentation');
   });
     const isSegment = segmentOfActiveLabelmapAtEvent(e); // If your mouse clicked any segments this will return an object otherwise undefined
      if(isSegment !== undefined) {
        // Here you can switch the colorLut index with your selected segment index, for example you can replace white color's index in colorLUT table
      }
   ```
3. Switching indexes in colorLUT, from any color to white

   ```
   /*
   * from:     Desired colors index
   * to:       selectedSegment index
   * colorLUT: colorLUTTable array
   * element:  Active element
   */
   const switchColorLUT = (from, to, colorLUT, element) => {
       const updatedLUT = [...colorLUT];
       [updatedLUT[from], updatedLUT[to]] = [updatedLUT[to], updatedLUT[from]];
       const {state, getters, setters} = cornerstoneTools.getModule('segmentation');
       state.colorLutTables[0] = updatedLUT
       setters.activeSegmentIndex(element, to)
       setters.activeLabelmapIndex(element, 0);
       cornerstone.updateImage(element)
   }
   ```

   You can use this function to update the colorLUT table:

   ```
   // Inside `cornerstonetoolsmouseclick` event
   switchColorLUT(COLORLIST.length -1, isSegment.segmentIndex, COLORLIST, element);
   ```

   This will update the selected segment to a white color.